# What is the difference between Regex syntax in Ruby vs Perl?

Tags: ruby, regex

In my understanding, when Matz invented Ruby, he pretty much lifted a lot of Perl language constructs and duplicated them. Does this extend to regular expressions as well, or are there any syntactical differences that I should be aware of?

Comment: Yes, there are significant differences bewteen the two, and many many outright omissions from Ruby. The Unicode support in Ruby is especially lacking. Example available upon request.

Comment: Perl regex features which Ruby lacks include: `\w \s \b \d` work on Unicode; `\h \H \v \V` for Unicode whitespace; `\R` for a Unicode linebreak grapheme; ***EVERY*** Unicode property supported; *user-defined* character properties; `\X` to match a Unicode grapheme cluster **⇐IMPORTANT⇒** named characters like `\N{SECTION SIGN}`; *user-defined* named characters; `\K` for unlimited lookbehind; conditional patterns like `(?(?=\w)(?<!\w)|(?<=\w))`; possessive quantifiers like `++`; branch reset operator `(?|…|…|…)`; support for arrays of named captures via `%-`; ***perl -Mre=debug***; code inserts

Comment: @steenslag There’s more, like code inserts for debugging or re-evaluation, pluggable regex engines, overloadable regex constants, backtracking control verbs, taint control on interpolation, and various other bits of finishing touches on the whole regex experience. A really superbig one for my kind of work is that Ruby makes no attempt to meet even the Level 1 comformance requirements of [UTS#18 Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/), the bare minimum for working with Unicode, let alone the various level-2 and level-3 things that Perl also meets. ***Unicode is a must.***

Comment: @tchrist I'm not able to verify if Ruby 1.9.3 now complies  with Level 1. As far as i can see, it does now support more than the minimum of [character properties](http://ruby.runpaint.org/regexps#properties). That document also mentions possessive quantifiers. Arrays of named values would be done with either String#scan or Regexp#named_captions, I guess. Other points you mention: conditional patterns are absent indeed. I don't know enough about the subject to say anything about the rest. My point is, regexp support may not be Perl-class yet, but it's moving forward fast.

Answer (score 3):

There's an extensive comparison of regex support in many languages at https://www.regular-expressions.info/refbasic.html and its sibling pages. Enter the two languages that you want to compare w.r.t. support of regex capabilities, and see the differences in the table.