# How do I write a regex for Excel cell range?

Tags: ruby, regex, excel

I need to validate that something is an Excel cell range in Ruby, i.e: "A4:A6". By looking at it, the requirement I am looking for is:

`<Alphabetical, Capitalised><Integer>:<Integer><Alphabetical, Capitalised>`

I am not sure how to form a RegExp for this.
I would appreciate a small explanation for a solution, as opposed to purely a solution.

A bonus would be to check that the range is restricted to within a row or column. I think this would be out of scope of Regular Expressions though.

I have tried `/[A-Z]+[0-9]+:[A-Z]+[0-9]+/` this works but allows extra characters on the ends.

This does not work because it allows extra's to be added on to the beginning or end:

`"HELLOAA3:A7".match(/\A[A-Z]+[0-9]+:[A-Z]+[0-9]+\z/)` also returns a match, but is more on the right track.

How would I limit the number range to 10000?
How would I limit the number of characters to 3?

Comment: What have *you* tried? Don't *you* want a bonus? :)

Comment: See EDIT 2, it doesn't work because if I have anything extra: `AZ100:B65hello` still gives a match.

Comment: I don't understand what "...the range is restricted to within a row or column." means. Can you give an example? btw, when I first skimmed your question I thought I read "bonus check", which got me pretty excited.

Comment: While we'd like to help, we need a more detailed example of your input data. What does "seems to work" mean? What caveats do you fear?

Comment: What I meant is that:
A1:A3 run in the same column - allow,
A1:C1 run in the same row  - allow,
A1:C3 run in more than one dimension - disallow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do both: match Excel range and that they must be same row or column. [Stub](http://rubular.com/r/rivR7m49tn)

```
^([A-Z]+)(\d+):(\1\d+|[A-Z]+\2)$

A4:A6             // ok
A5:B10            // not ok
B5:Z5             // ok
AZ100:B100hello   // not ok
```

The magic here is the back-reference group:

```
([A-Z]+)(\d+)     -- column is in capture group 1, row in group 2
(\1\d+|[A-Z]+\2)  -- the first column followed by any number; or
                  -- the first row preceded by any character
```

Comment: Great solution! Taking this further, lets say it has four parts:
`(col)(row):(col):(row)`. How do I extract those four parts into four variables?

Comment: John, `"A5:B10".scan /[A-Z]+|\d+/ #=> ["A", "5", "B", "10"] ` will provide that information.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution:

```
(?:(?:\'?(?:\[(?<wbook>.+)\])?(?<sheet>.+?)\'?!)?(?<colabs>\$)?(?<col>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<rowabs>\$)?(?<row>\d+)(?::(?<col2abs>\$)?(?<col2>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<row2abs>\$)?(?<row2>\d+))?|(?<name>[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\d]*))
```

It includes named ranges, but the R1C1 notation is not supported.
The pattern is written in perl compatible regex dialect (i.e. can also be used with C#), I'm not familiar with Ruby, so I can't tell the difference, but you may want to look here: [What is the difference between Regex syntax in Ruby vs Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520325/what-is-the-difference-between-regex-syntax-in-ruby-vs-perl)